# usb_cam stops sending responses sometime while running the rosservice with an error

Tags: ros

`[DEBUG] [1707888864.976035]: [/usb_cam/image_raw] failed to receive incoming message : unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details`

after some time again usb_cam/image_raw starts working and then agin it fails with same error for some seconds.

Comment: Please [edit] with the new lines in `sudo dmesg` that appear around that time

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.